# iPhone Push Notification (non-English message)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, notifications

I'm trying to send iPhone Push Notification (Arabic message) using UTF-8 characters.

JSON I get:

{"aps":{"alert":"\u00da\u00e3\u00d1","sound":"push2.aiff"}}

But in iPhone, I get: UaN

How can I send non-English message?

Answer (score 0):

The package that you send to the Apple push notification server is in JSON format. If you check http://www.json.org you'll see that all JSON strings must be Unicode. In your alert text you have specified the three Unicode code points 0xda 0xe3 and 0xd1 which are for "ÚãÑ".

If you want Arabic then you need to get your Arabic text represented as Unicode. You can then either embed them directly in the text or use \u escapes to define them as UTF-16 code points.